# Navbar fix needed

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my navbar to the top-center of my website, but I can't get rid of the small spaces between my buttons.
I tried many different CSS properties, but without success.

Also, my  inside the navbar is not at the very center, but a little bit to the right?
How come?

Finally, I added some media queries at the bottom and they also have some unwanted space on the left.
Plus, they are not really centered in the very middle.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHSab/96/

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="#logo"><img class="topleftlogo" src="images/logo.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: if this is a navbar, the appropriate html5 container element is `<nav>` not `<header>`

Comment: See the duplicate for details on the spacing inbetween.  For the centering issue, it is because there is padding on the `ul`. Try adding `padding-left:0px;` for the `ul`.

Comment: Thanks! Padding-left works well, now I just need to fix those unwanted spaces in between buttons.

Comment: for fix unwanted spaces, remove this : `display:inline` from `header ul li` and add `float:left; list-style:none;`

Comment: @artSX: Spaces are gone but now my buttons are not centered, they are all position t the left

Comment: @C.Felipe arf sorry, with the float:left; you cant center ul if you dont put width on <ul> but we have one a very academic approach to this problem space, try this => on `header ul li {margin-left:-4px;}`

Comment: I solved spaces with a suggestion bellow but now I have just one small space at the bottom??? http://jsfiddle.net/RHSab/110/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header{text-align: center;}

header ul{

    display: inline-block;

    overflow: hidden;

}

header ul li{float: left;}`

Comment: Almost perfect. What's the new unwanted space below??? http://jsfiddle.net/RHSab/108/

Comment: header ul{vertical-align:top;}

Comment: Why does the text on my navbar is not centered when I resize my browser to @media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width : 768px)

Comment: you have one line with `header ul li {
    width: 768px;
}` remove 768px and add 100%

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate your kindness very much. And the patience with beginners. You helped me a lot as I was cracking my head with this since yesterday...

Answer (score 2):

you need to add css on ul

```
ul {
   padding-left: 0;
}

header ul li {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

header a {
   padding: 0;
   height: 30px;
   color: white;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
   height: 60px;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   font-weight: 700;
}
```

It will center on its own.

Comment: I already did as Kami above suggested. But I am still fighting with the spaces between my buttons

Comment: I dont see any buttons

Comment: yea which buttons u r talking about ?

Comment: @C.Felipe which browser are you using and can you show us printscreen with those spaces? Cause I don't see any.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I call my links buttons which is not appropriate. Still a beginner :(

Comment: just tel me exactly what you want to do ?? you want to decrease your menu link height ? which spaces you are talking of ??

Comment: All is fine now, except that my menu is not centered when I resize my browser to @media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width : 768px) That's at the bottom of my CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Solved! Here is what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/RHSab/114/ Thanks for help!